# ng-model from select is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an select box in html with some options generated from an ng-repeat.

```
<select ng-model="pageId" ng-change="setFacebookPage()">
    <option ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-value="page.id"> {{page.name}}</option>
</select>
```

That works. The value and the options are shown correct. But I want to get the value of pageId in my function `setFacebookPage()` and that's where it goes wrong, because pageId is undefined in the controller!

```
$scope.setFacebookPage = function(){
    console.log("setFacebookPage", $scope.pageId);
}
```

But when I change the value of pageId I can see it's value with {{pageId}}.

I have tried to give it's value as an parameter in the function like `setFacebookPage(pageId)`, but that gives me also an undefined.

What the reason for this and how can I solve this?

Comment: There is not input type `select`. Use the select element instead

Answer (score 2):

There are small errors in your code.

- Use `select` element
- Comma between attributes are not allowed

Hence, update your code to following

```
 <select ng-model="pageId" ng-change="setFacebookPage()">
     <option ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-value="page.id"> {{page.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

You can tweak [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/icp8D4fZJXigPh4eh9ih?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I use pug and I have make some faults while typing the basic html ;) I have updated my question.

Comment: @NVO - I am able to get the value of pageId in the function. Have you checked the plunker I have shared in answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
 <select ng-model="pageId" ng-change="setFacebookPage()">
      <option ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-value="page.id"> {{page.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

instead of

```
<input type="select" ng-model="pageId", ng-change="setFacebookPage()">
    <option ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-value="page.id"> {{page.name}}</option>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.pages = [{"id" : 1, "name" : "sachin"}, {"id" : 2, "name" : "sourav"}];
  $scope.setFacebookPage = function(){
    console.log( $scope.pageId);
}


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  <body ng-app="demo" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="pageId" ng-change="setFacebookPage()">
      <option ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-value="page.id"> {{page.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </body>
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I use pug and I have make some faults while typing the basic html ;) I have updated my question.

Comment: @NVO chec the demo